# You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async. in django channels

Tags: python, django, websocket, async-await, django-channels

**This is my code of django channels.How to obtain the data it gives the error You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.**

```py
class WaitlistConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()
        try:
            asyncio.ensure_future(self.send_data())
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        self.task.cancel()

    async def send_data(self):
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(3)
            try:
                waitlist =await sync_to_async(Waitlist.objects.all)()
                print(waitlist)
            
                
                if waitlist.exists():
                        print("first name")
                        data={"first_name":waitlist[0].first_name}
                else:
                        data = {"first_name": "No one is waiting"}
                await self.send(json.dumps(data))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```